# Fireworks crashing on opening (CS6 and CS5) Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Mavericks

Tags: crash, fireworks

Mac Fireworks CS6 and CS5 won't start.
Even after trying all suggested solutions on the Adobe forum, ranging from removing the fireworks preferences to remove all user fonts of my mac system.

After loading the fireworks always remains not responding and I have to force quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe me, it's all because of Flash Firebug in FIREFOX!
I disabled flash firebug in firefox, restarted firefox, removed the flash firebub, closed firefox, opened the fireworks, and happiness returned to my macbook. After much time and many attempts the fireworks works again.

I can not believe that a firefox plugin could cause me so much trouble.

Here is the source of the solution that saved my day: http://www.hightechdad.com/2012/04/23/how-to-fix-adobe-fireworks-hanging-after-launch-on-macos/

Comment: Wow.  THANK YOU so much for this.  I've been troubleshooting this issue for hours and would have never figured it out without your answer.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

None of the three other answers here solved my problem.

My problem (Fireworks CS5.1 OS X 10.9) was on launch automatically reopening a particular file hung Fireworks. Launching as a different user worked fine so I tried deleting all adobe preferences, turning off opening windows on application launch (actually enabled 'Close Windows when quitting an application' in Settings->General) but this didn't work. Finally worked out that Fireworks keeps its open document state in user/Library/Saved Application/State/com.macromedia.fireworks.savedState.

Deleting this folder cured my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks wipes Java from your system. I had to manually install it from apple to get illustrator to work. Might be the same issue:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that a installation from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 solved my problem with Fireworks CS5, Illustrator CS5 and Photoshop CS5.

My problem was: after upgrading to Mavericks none of the CS5 apps worked. I found the link here http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1320137

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue here.  Every time, I tried starting Fireworks CS6, I would see that it was trying to load several old images and it would eventually crash.  I even unistalled and re-installed Fireworks, but it was still happening.  The fix for me was exactly what wheeliebin posted above.  I delete the com.macromedia.fireworks.savedState directory and now my Fireworks CS6 works again.

Comment: Renaming/deleting the folder, 'user/Library/Saved Application/State/com.macromedia.fireworks.savedState' corrected my issue. Thank you! If you cannot find this folder... It is hidden - you have to hold down the option key and then select the Go menu in the Finder. Library will be shown and that's your user Library. Search for 'Saved Application State'.